# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED docker wordpress image

Tags: wordpress, docker

I'm new to docker and I'm trying to use wordpress container downloaded from the docker registry. I'm using macOS and docker desktop, I'm havong a bad time to try starting wordpress setup because I'm unable to connect to localhost also if the docker image is running. I've done a research and found this old post where is suggested to use the command `docker run -p 8080:8080 wordpress` but seems not work and I will get a connection refused in safari or chrome. What is the correct way to start the container so I can setup my dev enviroiment for wordpress?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this docker image you running may contain only the php part of WordPress, you need to set MySQL also to run the WordPress successfully.

You can give MYsql Credentials in env like:

`docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name my-wp -e WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=your-db-host -e WORDPRESS_DB_USER=your-db-username -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=your-db-password -e WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=your-db-name wordpress`

you can check log of the docker container by `docker log <container id>` command.

Comment: I need to run mysql separately or it's included inside the image?